# Locking order in a nested query

Tags: mysql, locking, transaction, deadlock

I'm trying to prevent deadlocks in my code because i may use both in different parts of my project.

Do they lock rows in the same order?

1. **Nested**

   ```sql
   select * from `carts`
   where `carts`.`user_id` = ? and exists (
       select * from `cart_items` where `carts`.`id` = `cart_items`.`cart_id` for update
   ) for update
   ```
2. **Separate**

   ```
   select * from `carts` where `carts`.`user_id` = ? for update
   ```

   ```
   select * from `cart_items` where `cart_id` = ? for update
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `START TRANSACTION` ie before it/them and the `COMMIT` is after, think of it this way:  The locking starts at the time of the `START`.

Or this way...  If two transactions are doing

```
UPDATE ... WHERE id IN (11,22)
```

one can wait for the other to finish (cf `lock_wait_timeout`).

If, instead, another did `WHERE id (22, 11)`, there could be a deadlock.  In that case, one would be rolled back, and the other would continue to completion.

I suspect that a statement with a nested `EXISTS` is faster than two statements, so I would try to do the former in both cases.

Also, be aware, that sometimes "gaps" around ids are locked.  And sometimes the gap locking either does not make sense or does not show up clearly in `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;`.

Bottom line:  plan for the worst.  Be ready to replay any transaction that was rolled back due to a deadlock.